# Regex for special symbols

Tags: regex

I`m using this regexp for special-symbols-only word

```
(?m)^[._^%*&$#!~@,-]+$
```

Do we have something like `\p{L}` for special symbols only?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the best you will get is `\W` which is shorthand for "not a word character" (equivalent of `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`) but it will match against more than what is currently in your list

Comment: @CrayonViolent, thanks. It was my first thought, but I was interested in finding more "elegant" way to solve that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-unicode-general-categories has a bunch of options for unicode categories you can select by. I have no idea of the support outside of .NET - I am aware that different places implement regex slightly differently in terms of what they support  so I offer this only as a possibly useful reference. Whether what you consider "special symbols only" matches with one of those categories (eg all Punctuation?) is for you to decide.

Comment: could possibly try a negative lookahead: `(?:(?!\p{L}).)+`

Comment: What is wrong with the way you wrote it?

Comment: @CrayonViolent how is that better than the shorter and more portable `[^\p{L}]` ? Also, since `\p{L}` only match letters, both our propositions will also match numbers

Comment: @Aaron I suppose I forgot you could put that stuff in char classes.  Offhand I can't think of any reason it's better, though I can't think of any reason it's worse, either, since virtually every language allows lookaheads (I guess maybe if you wanna throw stuff like glob (or some half baked dev program's regex functionality (like html-kit) into the mix..) But as for me only showing `\p{L}` I only matched what OP did since he wasn't exactly explicit about what constitutes "special symbols" to him, and I expected him to build on that

Comment: @CrayonViolent looks like [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/O4YXUv/1) is twice slower than [mine](https://regex101.com/r/6WnbtQ/1/). Also neither ERE nor BRE support lookarounds, but are widely used in shell scripts. It's also interesting to note that mine matches linefeeds, while yours doesn't since `.` doesn't match them without DOTALL. I feel like lookarounds should be avoided when more basic features can be used instead, but I might have a bias because I learned regex before they were a thing.

Comment: @Aaron I get it, you're awesome. How dare I swoop in here to help someone instead of letting you, the regex master, do your thing. Please oh please forgive my ignorance, and I promise next time I will know my place.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Come on man, I'm sorry you took it this way but this kind of comment has no place on this website. I do mistakes all the time and I'm glad when someone's here to correct me ; why can't you just learn from the facts I presented? Was I at some point rude or generally unpleasant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get all the ascii special symbols  `(?=[\x{21}-\x{7e}])[\W_]`

32 characters

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Hardcoded in different syntax:

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]  
[\x{21}-\x{2F}\x{3A}-\x{40}\x{5B}-\x{60}\x{7B}-\x{7E}]  
[\u{21}-\u{2F}\u{3A}-\u{40}\u{5B}-\u{60}\u{7B}-\u{7E}]  
[\u0021-\u002F\u003A-\u0040\u005B-\u0060\u007B-\u007E]
```

**_____________________**

Same as above but excludes the escape char `(?=[\x{21}-\x{5b}\x{5d}-\x{7e}])[\W_]`

31 characters

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~
```

Hardcoded in different syntax:

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]
[\x{21}-\x{2F}\x{3A}-\x{40}\x{5B}\x{5D}-\x{60}\x{7B}-\x{7E}]
[\u{21}-\u{2F}\u{3A}-\u{40}\u{5B}\u{5D}-\u{60}\u{7B}-\u{7E}]
[\u0021-\u002F\u003A-\u0040\u005B\u005D-\u0060\u007B-\u007E]
```

Comment: A full on Unicode all-range regex is pretty big. I can try  that for you if needed. And there is no category of _special_ characters property. It has to be deduced. Usually though, for password's, the range above ascii is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like thing that I was looking for.